# How can I get the next bot or operator message after the bot says "give me a minute"?

Tags: sql, time, google-bigquery

Im trying to analyze difference in time stamps between a specific message a bot says ("give me a minute")

I need to see timestamp of the bot message and the message from either bot or operator after said message from the bot

Also need to display the id and operator name whenever the subsequent message is from the operator

```
SELECT m1.session_id, m1.creation_time, m1.message AS bot_message, m2.creation_time as user_date, m2.message AS operator_message
inner join ext_metric_felixpago.message_metrics m2
  ON m1.session_id = m2.session_id
WHERE m1.msg_from = 'bot'
  AND m1.message = 'Dame un minuto para ayudarte '
  AND (m2.msg_from = 'operator' or m2.msg_from ='user')
  AND m2.creation_time > m1.creation_time
  AND m1.creation_time >= "2023-03-27"
ORDER BY m1.creation_time desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a join condition to connect the first bot message (m1) to the subsequent message (m2).
 
SELECT m1.session_id, m1.creation_time, m1.message AS bot_message,
       m2.creation_time AS user_date, m2.message AS operator_message,
       m2.msg_from AS message_from, m2.operator_id, o.name AS operator_name
FROM ext_metric_felixpago.message_metrics m1
INNER JOIN ext_metric_felixpago.message_metrics m2
  ON m1.session_id = m2.session_id
LEFT JOIN operators o
  ON m2.operator_id = o.id
WHERE m1.msg_from = 'bot'
  AND m1.message = 'Dame un minuto para ayudarte '
  AND m2.creation_time > m1.creation_time
  AND m1.creation_time >= "2023-03-27"
ORDER BY m1.creation_time DESC;